# Live-Server Extension VS Code Not Working

Tags: npm-live-server

I have some problem with my Live-Server Extension on VS code. It actually is not working. It only works when i go to browser and manually refresh the page. I have tried each and every solution from the other website but nothing works for me. is there anyone who can help me, would be greatful to you. thank you very much!

Comment: we need anything concrete to help you. a piece of your code would be just fine..

Comment: Like i mean, here is the simple code which i am trying to run
here is the screenshot of the code
https://ibb.co/zHLqbqY
and my live server extension is also enabled, but that extension is not working. The changes i made in the code does reload in the browser automatically until i go to browser and manually refresh the page.
thats what i am trying to say i hope you understand

Comment: here is the piece of code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>testing Document</h1>
  
</body>
</html>

Comment: Any error message at the bottom of VS Code?

Comment: @Mr.Bean no there is no error in the bottom. But still i have to go the browser and manually refresh the page to see the changes

Comment: To be honest, it's been very cranky with me recently

Comment: @Mr.Bean can you help me? i dont want to install new windows so am trying to fix it

Comment: You can try typing in "localhost...." etc..in the url bar, but you will have to manually refresh. It maybe a bug in the extension. I don't know what is happening with it. Sometimes the page that I'm using suddenly becomes busy and tries to reload. I am assuming  of course you are using apache server on your computer, something like Xampp

Comment: @Mr.Bean yes i had Xamp on my laptop for my studies but i already uninstalled Xamp and the issue is still their.

Comment: @Mr.Bean i can share my screen on zoom or discord with you if you can help me pleaseeeeeee

Comment: I don't prefer either, sorry, I value my privacy. Alternatives are also not ok

Comment: can anyone else help me with this?

Comment: Did you disable it by any chance?

Comment: @Mr.Bean no i didn't disabled anything i am just using npm parcel package because live server not working for me
sry for late respond!

Comment: Can I ask what you are developing? PHP, reactjs, laravel etc...?

Comment: yes javascript.

Comment: Are you sure that the javascript code actually works? Does it call a server-side script?

Comment: Are you sure it's javascript and not jquery?

Comment: yes its simple javascript with html and css